# Animation SVG not playing on a server but playing on an other

Tags: animation, svg

I've this SVG animation :
http://jeuderologie.fr/share/hom_intro_arrows.svg

You can see the arrow fade and loop infintly. It's nice, it's what is expected.

But the same svg file on another server (I can't give a link for security reason) stay fixed on the draw and never play the animation.

How this is possible? Is there some configuration to make on a server to play the svg animation?

Here the code  if it can help...

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="216 4.3 527 760" enable-background="new 216 4.3 527 760" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#0FF" stroke-width="40" stroke-miterlimit="10" opacity="1" points="728.9,18.7 480,261.3 249.8,18.7">
            <animate id="anim1" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="0s;anim12.end+0.1s" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="1" dur="0.1s"></animate>
            <animate id="anim12" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="anim3.end" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="1" to="0" dur="0.3s"></animate>
        </polyline>

        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#F0F" stroke-width="40" stroke-miterlimit="10" opacity="1" points="728.9,261.3 480,510.2 237.3,261.3">
            <animate id="anim2" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="anim1.end" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="1" dur="0.1s"></animate>
            <animate id="anim22" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="anim3.end" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="1" to="0" dur="0.3s"></animate>
        </polyline>

        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FF0" stroke-width="40" stroke-miterlimit="10" opacity="1" points="721.9,487 473,735.9 230.3,487">
            <animate id="anim3" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="anim2.end" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="0" to="1" dur="0.1s"></animate>
            <animate id="anim32" attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" fill="freeze" accumulate="none" begin="anim3.end" additive="replace" calcMode="linear" from="1" to="0" dur="0.3s"></animate>
        </polyline>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistery is resolved.
It wasn't a server problem.
I used a minification on a project and the svg was changed, breaking so the animation.

A little shame for me, but good to know.